# A way to access json data

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am importing a json file as 'data' to use it as a initial state of chatList. However,

> Property does not exist on type

keeps showing up. Is there a way that I can access chats in data? ->
data is an array too, so it should be for example data[0].chats –
Apostolos : Thanks a lot!

```
 [
  {
    "partnerId": "user1",
    "chats": [
      {
        "userId": "user0",
        "message": "Olaf, you are melting!",
        "msgId": 1644809969390
      },
      {
        "userId": "user1",
        "message": "Some people are worth melting for",
        "msgId": 1644809969387
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "partnerId": "user2",
    "chats": [
      {
        "userId": "user2",
        "message": "11111",
        "msgId": 1644809969392
      },
```

How can I access certain partnerId so that I can filter chats and set as the initial state of chatList?

Comment: data is an array too, so it should be for example `data[0].chats`

Comment: check my answer regarding the other issue you have

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by a specific partnerId, then you should do the following:

```
const [chatList, setChatList] = useState<IChat[]>(data
.filter(dt => dt.partnerId === 'ABCD')
.map(t => t.chats).flat()
.filter(user => user.userId === 'XYZ')
```